# Netlogo - selecting a value from a weighted list based on a randomly drawn number

Tags: netlogo

I'm looking for some help with selecting a value from a weighted list based on a randomly drawn number.

Think of my list as an empirical cumulative distribution function for a random variable, where the random variable is flood-prob. The first number in each pair of the list represents a depth and the last number in the pair is the weight/probability.

Suppose the random number drawn for the flood-prob variable is 0.66, how would I then select the corresponding depth from my list? or the approximate value?

```
extensions [ rnd ]

globals [probabilities depths ecdf flood-prob]

to-report create-ecdf
  set probabilities [0.056 0.061 0.073 0.083 0.087 0.095 0.103 0.110 0.115 0.117 0.121 0.125 0.132 0.135 0.141 0.144 0.146 0.153 0.158 0.161 0.166 0.171 0.176 0.183 0.186 0.193 0.199 0.205 0.206 0.211 0.219 0.225 0.229 0.232 0.242 0.246 0.253 0.256 0.261 0.270 0.273 0.280 0.290 0.293 0.300 0.309 0.315 0.317 0.328 0.332 0.335 0.342 0.348 0.357 0.360 0.369 0.379 0.383 0.392 0.399 0.403 0.415 0.424 0.429 0.432 0.442 0.447 0.450 0.462 0.463 0.472 0.486 0.491 0.499 0.507 0.520 0.525 0.540 0.548 0.561 0.571 0.583 0.596 0.605 0.612 0.628 0.636 0.646 0.661 0.679 0.685 0.695 0.715 0.726 0.735 0.752 0.762 0.771 0.790 0.800 0.814 0.826 0.836 0.847 0.859 0.872 0.880 0.883 0.898 0.904 0.911 0.920 0.926 0.935 0.939 0.953 0.957 0.967 0.974 0.979 0.986 0.987 0.993 0.997 0.999]
  set depths [2.80399990081787 2.82999992370605 2.88599991798401 2.92899990081787 2.94400000572205 2.97499990463257 3.00300002098083 3.02500009536743 3.04200005531311 3.04800009727478 3.06100010871887 3.07200002670288 3.09299993515015 3.1010000705719 3.11800003051758 3.125 3.13100004196167 3.14800000190735 3.16100001335144 3.17000007629395 3.18099999427795 3.19400000572205 3.20600008964539 3.22300004959106 3.22900009155273 3.24499988555908 3.2590000629425 3.27099990844727 3.27300000190735 3.28299999237061 3.29999995231628 3.31200003623962 3.3199999332428 3.32699990272522 3.34599995613098 3.35400009155273 3.36800003051758 3.37400007247925 3.3840000629425 3.3989999294281 3.40599989891052 3.41899991035461 3.43600010871887 3.44099998474121 3.4539999961853 3.46900010108948 3.48000001907349 3.48399996757507 3.50200009346008 3.50799989700317 3.51399993896484 3.52500009536743 3.53500008583069 3.54999995231628 3.5550000667572 3.5699999332428 3.58599996566772 3.59299993515015 3.60700011253357 3.61800003051758 3.62400007247925 3.64299988746643 3.65700006484985 3.66499996185303 3.66899991035461 3.68499994277954 3.69300007820129 3.69700002670288 3.71499991416931 3.71799993515015 3.73099994659424 3.75200009346008 3.75999999046326 3.77300000190735 3.78500008583069 3.80399990081787 3.81299996376038 3.83500003814697 3.84800004959106 3.86800003051758 3.88299989700317 3.90199995040894 3.92199993133545 3.93600010871887 3.94799995422363 3.97300004959106 3.98699998855591 4.00299978256226 4.02799987792969 4.05800008773804 4.06799983978271 4.08500003814697 4.11999988555908 4.1399998664856 4.15799999237061 4.19000005722046 4.20900011062622 4.22800016403198 4.26599979400635 4.28800010681152 4.31799983978271 4.34700012207031 4.37099981307983 4.39900016784668 4.42999982833862 4.46600008010864 4.49100017547607 4.5 4.55100011825562 4.57000017166138 4.59600019454956 4.63199996948242 4.65500020980835 4.69799995422363 4.7189998626709 4.7979998588562 4.82399988174438 4.89799976348877 4.95699977874756 5.02099990844727 5.11899995803833 5.13100004196167 5.27099990844727 5.44799995422363 5.64300012588501] 
  set ecdf (map list depths probabilities) ;; First number is depth, second number is probability.
  set flood-prob random-normal 0.26 0.22

;; Need help from here onwards in selecting the appropriate value...
  
end
```

I have tried using rnd:weighted-one-of-list but it is unsuitable. I think I need some code that uses the drawn value of flood-prob to relate to an item index in the list that is approximate to it, from which I can extract the corresponding depth.

I've been stuck on this for a while so any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I second Luke's remarks on (1) making sure whether you want to use `random-normal` rather than just a uniform 0-to-1 sample, considering that the values in the `probabilities` list already shape the distribution (**but there is more to this, I'll talk about it at the end of the answer**), and (2) moving the creation of your global values to `setup` so that this happens only once.

That said, here I propose a different, light approach to achieve your goal which only relies on the two existing lists and might also have the advantage of readability.

In English: create your random value and compare it to each value in the `probabilities` list, in order, until you find a value in the `probabilities` list that is not smaller than the random value. Keep track of the position of the item (from `probabilities`) being compared. When you find the probability value that is not smaller than the random value, extract the item from `depths` that is found in the same position.

In NetLogo:

```
globals [ depths probabilities ]

to setup
  clear-all
  set depths [2.80399990081787 2.82999992370605 2.88599991798401 2.92899990081787 2.94400000572205 2.97499990463257 3.00300002098083 3.02500009536743 3.04200005531311 3.04800009727478 3.06100010871887 3.07200002670288 3.09299993515015 3.1010000705719 3.11800003051758 3.125 3.13100004196167 3.14800000190735 3.16100001335144 3.17000007629395 3.18099999427795 3.19400000572205 3.20600008964539 3.22300004959106 3.22900009155273 3.24499988555908 3.2590000629425 3.27099990844727 3.27300000190735 3.28299999237061 3.29999995231628 3.31200003623962 3.3199999332428 3.32699990272522 3.34599995613098 3.35400009155273 3.36800003051758 3.37400007247925 3.3840000629425 3.3989999294281 3.40599989891052 3.41899991035461 3.43600010871887 3.44099998474121 3.4539999961853 3.46900010108948 3.48000001907349 3.48399996757507 3.50200009346008 3.50799989700317 3.51399993896484 3.52500009536743 3.53500008583069 3.54999995231628 3.5550000667572 3.5699999332428 3.58599996566772 3.59299993515015 3.60700011253357 3.61800003051758 3.62400007247925 3.64299988746643 3.65700006484985 3.66499996185303 3.66899991035461 3.68499994277954 3.69300007820129 3.69700002670288 3.71499991416931 3.71799993515015 3.73099994659424 3.75200009346008 3.75999999046326 3.77300000190735 3.78500008583069 3.80399990081787 3.81299996376038 3.83500003814697 3.84800004959106 3.86800003051758 3.88299989700317 3.90199995040894 3.92199993133545 3.93600010871887 3.94799995422363 3.97300004959106 3.98699998855591 4.00299978256226 4.02799987792969 4.05800008773804 4.06799983978271 4.08500003814697 4.11999988555908 4.1399998664856 4.15799999237061 4.19000005722046 4.20900011062622 4.22800016403198 4.26599979400635 4.28800010681152 4.31799983978271 4.34700012207031 4.37099981307983 4.39900016784668 4.42999982833862 4.46600008010864 4.49100017547607 4.5 4.55100011825562 4.57000017166138 4.59600019454956 4.63199996948242 4.65500020980835 4.69799995422363 4.7189998626709 4.7979998588562 4.82399988174438 4.89799976348877 4.95699977874756 5.02099990844727 5.11899995803833 5.13100004196167 5.27099990844727 5.44799995422363 5.64300012588501]
  set probabilities [0.056 0.061 0.073 0.083 0.087 0.095 0.103 0.110 0.115 0.117 0.121 0.125 0.132 0.135 0.141 0.144 0.146 0.153 0.158 0.161 0.166 0.171 0.176 0.183 0.186 0.193 0.199 0.205 0.206 0.211 0.219 0.225 0.229 0.232 0.242 0.246 0.253 0.256 0.261 0.270 0.273 0.280 0.290 0.293 0.300 0.309 0.315 0.317 0.328 0.332 0.335 0.342 0.348 0.357 0.360 0.369 0.379 0.383 0.392 0.399 0.403 0.415 0.424 0.429 0.432 0.442 0.447 0.450 0.462 0.463 0.472 0.486 0.491 0.499 0.507 0.520 0.525 0.540 0.548 0.561 0.571 0.583 0.596 0.605 0.612 0.628 0.636 0.646 0.661 0.679 0.685 0.695 0.715 0.726 0.735 0.752 0.762 0.771 0.790 0.800 0.814 0.826 0.836 0.847 0.859 0.872 0.880 0.883 0.898 0.904 0.911 0.920 0.926 0.935 0.939 0.953 0.957 0.967 0.974 0.979 0.986 0.987 0.993 0.997 0.999]
end

to-report depth-based-on-probability
  let this-random-number random-normal 0.26 0.22
  let index 0
  
  while [this-random-number > item index probabilities] [
    set index index + 1
  ]
  
  report item index depths
end
```

However, note that while this is a fast and light approach, it still needs some aspects to be fixed which require some further considerations. See below.

### Notes regarding the way you draw your random number

`random-normal` can generate values that are outside of your range of `probabilities`. This is true in general, but also very much in particular for your `random-normal 0.26 0.22`.

1. It can give negative numbers but negative numbers are not contemplated in your `probabilities` list. You would not get an error in that case, because `this-random-number > item index probabilities` will evaluate as `FALSE` on the first iteration of `while` and the procedure will just report the first element of `depths`. However this makes me wonder whether occasionally having negative values is something you planned for, considering that the effect of this is to increase the probability that the first element of `depths` is extracted (i.e. "increase" beyond the level specified in `probabilities`, which is 0.056). Using `random-float 1` instead of `random-normal` will eliminate this issue while still following the shape of your distribution, because the shape is given by the values in `probabilities`.
2. I see that your `probabilities` reach 0.999. There is absolutely no guarantee that `random-normal 0.26 0.22` will give values lower than 0.999, as it can actually give values that are not only greater than 0.999 but also greater than 1. This will give you an error, because at some point the `index` value will grow to the point that `item index probabilities` does not exist, and the model will interrupt with an error. If my understanding is correct, your intention is to have `probabilities` and `depths` such that these two lists map all the possible events. Again, a correct way to do it would be to use `random-float 1` (which guarantees that you get a value 0 <= x < 1) AND setting the last item of your `probabilities` list as 1 (and not 0.999).

Summarising the above, the resulting code would look like:

```
globals [ depths probabilities ]

to setup
  clear-all
  set depths [2.80399990081787 2.82999992370605 2.88599991798401 2.92899990081787 2.94400000572205 2.97499990463257 3.00300002098083 3.02500009536743 3.04200005531311 3.04800009727478 3.06100010871887 3.07200002670288 3.09299993515015 3.1010000705719 3.11800003051758 3.125 3.13100004196167 3.14800000190735 3.16100001335144 3.17000007629395 3.18099999427795 3.19400000572205 3.20600008964539 3.22300004959106 3.22900009155273 3.24499988555908 3.2590000629425 3.27099990844727 3.27300000190735 3.28299999237061 3.29999995231628 3.31200003623962 3.3199999332428 3.32699990272522 3.34599995613098 3.35400009155273 3.36800003051758 3.37400007247925 3.3840000629425 3.3989999294281 3.40599989891052 3.41899991035461 3.43600010871887 3.44099998474121 3.4539999961853 3.46900010108948 3.48000001907349 3.48399996757507 3.50200009346008 3.50799989700317 3.51399993896484 3.52500009536743 3.53500008583069 3.54999995231628 3.5550000667572 3.5699999332428 3.58599996566772 3.59299993515015 3.60700011253357 3.61800003051758 3.62400007247925 3.64299988746643 3.65700006484985 3.66499996185303 3.66899991035461 3.68499994277954 3.69300007820129 3.69700002670288 3.71499991416931 3.71799993515015 3.73099994659424 3.75200009346008 3.75999999046326 3.77300000190735 3.78500008583069 3.80399990081787 3.81299996376038 3.83500003814697 3.84800004959106 3.86800003051758 3.88299989700317 3.90199995040894 3.92199993133545 3.93600010871887 3.94799995422363 3.97300004959106 3.98699998855591 4.00299978256226 4.02799987792969 4.05800008773804 4.06799983978271 4.08500003814697 4.11999988555908 4.1399998664856 4.15799999237061 4.19000005722046 4.20900011062622 4.22800016403198 4.26599979400635 4.28800010681152 4.31799983978271 4.34700012207031 4.37099981307983 4.39900016784668 4.42999982833862 4.46600008010864 4.49100017547607 4.5 4.55100011825562 4.57000017166138 4.59600019454956 4.63199996948242 4.65500020980835 4.69799995422363 4.7189998626709 4.7979998588562 4.82399988174438 4.89799976348877 4.95699977874756 5.02099990844727 5.11899995803833 5.13100004196167 5.27099990844727 5.44799995422363 5.64300012588501]
  set probabilities [0.056 0.061 0.073 0.083 0.087 0.095 0.103 0.110 0.115 0.117 0.121 0.125 0.132 0.135 0.141 0.144 0.146 0.153 0.158 0.161 0.166 0.171 0.176 0.183 0.186 0.193 0.199 0.205 0.206 0.211 0.219 0.225 0.229 0.232 0.242 0.246 0.253 0.256 0.261 0.270 0.273 0.280 0.290 0.293 0.300 0.309 0.315 0.317 0.328 0.332 0.335 0.342 0.348 0.357 0.360 0.369 0.379 0.383 0.392 0.399 0.403 0.415 0.424 0.429 0.432 0.442 0.447 0.450 0.462 0.463 0.472 0.486 0.491 0.499 0.507 0.520 0.525 0.540 0.548 0.561 0.571 0.583 0.596 0.605 0.612 0.628 0.636 0.646 0.661 0.679 0.685 0.695 0.715 0.726 0.735 0.752 0.762 0.771 0.790 0.800 0.814 0.826 0.836 0.847 0.859 0.872 0.880 0.883 0.898 0.904 0.911 0.920 0.926 0.935 0.939 0.953 0.957 0.967 0.974 0.979 0.986 0.987 0.993 0.997 1]
end

to-report depth-based-on-probability
  let this-random-number random-float 1
  let index 0
  
  while [this-random-number >= item index probabilities] [
    set index index + 1
  ]
  
  report item index depths
end
```

Note above the use of `random-float` and the new last item of `probabilities`.

However also note that an important difference is in the condition for `while`: I included `>=` instead of simply `>`. This has to do with the way conditions with `random-float` (or `random` if working with integers) are conceived in NetLogo. In fact, `random x` [reports a value greater than or equal to 0, but strictly less than x](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#random). This means that a 50% chance is represented by `random 2 < 1`, and you can write a 12% chance as `random 100 < 12` or `random-float 1 < 0.12`.

It follows that, looking for example at the first element of your lists, you want to extract the depth of 2.80399990081787 if `random-float 1 < 0.56`. It means that you want the condition to evaluate as `FALSE` when `this-random-number < item index probabilities`, which means that it has to evaluate as `TRUE` when `this-random-number >= item index probabilities`.

Having the last item of `probabilities` as 1 will ensure that `this-random-number >= item index probabilities` is always `FALSE` for the last item (because `random-float 1` is always strictly less than 1), which is exactly what you need when using `while` loops in order to avoid infinite loops or, in your case, runtime errors (as explained in point 2 above).

Comment: Does this approach return the nearest probability value, or the nearest value greater than the `random-float` number?

Comment: I would also note that this method is roughly 4 times faster (based on profiler) than the one I outlined- would potentially add up if there are a lot of calls to the reporter!

Comment: @LukeC Hey Luke, not sure I completely understood your question. This approach generates the `random-float 1` number, finds the nearest greater probability value in `probabilities`, and then reports the depth value found in the same position (in `depths`) as the nearest greater probability value (in `probabilities`). This makes sure, for example, that 2.88599991798401 (the third depth value) will be reported 1.2% of the times, because that's the interval between 0.061 and 0.073. Does this answer the question?

Comment: Yes, you've got it Matteo- I just wanted to clarify if a random value of 0.01 would be associated with 0.1 or 0.2 (if those were the closest bounds in a hypothetical `probablities` list.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using this ecdf in the way I'm imagining (to generate random points within your empirical distribution), you may want to confirm that `random-normal` is the correct distribution to sample for your generation rather than a random uniform selection from 0 to 1 to sample from the inverse cdf- but I may be misunderstanding your purpose here (and, I haven't looked at the shape of your provided points).

If you just want to match the closest values between your `flood-prob` and the list of possible probabilities, you could determine the minimum absolute differences between `flood-prob` and the list then use that new list to pull the index value to pull from your depths:

```
globals [ probabilities depths ]

to setup
  ca
  set probabilities [0.056 0.061 0.073 0.083 0.087 0.095 0.103 0.110 0.115 0.117 0.121 0.125 0.132 0.135 0.141 0.144 0.146 0.153 0.158 0.161 0.166 0.171 0.176 0.183 0.186 0.193 0.199 0.205 0.206 0.211 0.219 0.225 0.229 0.232 0.242 0.246 0.253 0.256 0.261 0.270 0.273 0.280 0.290 0.293 0.300 0.309 0.315 0.317 0.328 0.332 0.335 0.342 0.348 0.357 0.360 0.369 0.379 0.383 0.392 0.399 0.403 0.415 0.424 0.429 0.432 0.442 0.447 0.450 0.462 0.463 0.472 0.486 0.491 0.499 0.507 0.520 0.525 0.540 0.548 0.561 0.571 0.583 0.596 0.605 0.612 0.628 0.636 0.646 0.661 0.679 0.685 0.695 0.715 0.726 0.735 0.752 0.762 0.771 0.790 0.800 0.814 0.826 0.836 0.847 0.859 0.872 0.880 0.883 0.898 0.904 0.911 0.920 0.926 0.935 0.939 0.953 0.957 0.967 0.974 0.979 0.986 0.987 0.993 0.997 0.999]
  set depths [2.80399990081787 2.82999992370605 2.88599991798401 2.92899990081787 2.94400000572205 2.97499990463257 3.00300002098083 3.02500009536743 3.04200005531311 3.04800009727478 3.06100010871887 3.07200002670288 3.09299993515015 3.1010000705719 3.11800003051758 3.125 3.13100004196167 3.14800000190735 3.16100001335144 3.17000007629395 3.18099999427795 3.19400000572205 3.20600008964539 3.22300004959106 3.22900009155273 3.24499988555908 3.2590000629425 3.27099990844727 3.27300000190735 3.28299999237061 3.29999995231628 3.31200003623962 3.3199999332428 3.32699990272522 3.34599995613098 3.35400009155273 3.36800003051758 3.37400007247925 3.3840000629425 3.3989999294281 3.40599989891052 3.41899991035461 3.43600010871887 3.44099998474121 3.4539999961853 3.46900010108948 3.48000001907349 3.48399996757507 3.50200009346008 3.50799989700317 3.51399993896484 3.52500009536743 3.53500008583069 3.54999995231628 3.5550000667572 3.5699999332428 3.58599996566772 3.59299993515015 3.60700011253357 3.61800003051758 3.62400007247925 3.64299988746643 3.65700006484985 3.66499996185303 3.66899991035461 3.68499994277954 3.69300007820129 3.69700002670288 3.71499991416931 3.71799993515015 3.73099994659424 3.75200009346008 3.75999999046326 3.77300000190735 3.78500008583069 3.80399990081787 3.81299996376038 3.83500003814697 3.84800004959106 3.86800003051758 3.88299989700317 3.90199995040894 3.92199993133545 3.93600010871887 3.94799995422363 3.97300004959106 3.98699998855591 4.00299978256226 4.02799987792969 4.05800008773804 4.06799983978271 4.08500003814697 4.11999988555908 4.1399998664856 4.15799999237061 4.19000005722046 4.20900011062622 4.22800016403198 4.26599979400635 4.28800010681152 4.31799983978271 4.34700012207031 4.37099981307983 4.39900016784668 4.42999982833862 4.46600008010864 4.49100017547607 4.5 4.55100011825562 4.57000017166138 4.59600019454956 4.63199996948242 4.65500020980835 4.69799995422363 4.7189998626709 4.7979998588562 4.82399988174438 4.89799976348877 4.95699977874756 5.02099990844727 5.11899995803833 5.13100004196167 5.27099990844727 5.44799995422363 5.64300012588501]  
  reset-ticks
end

to-report pull-depth-from-dist  
  ; Random flood dist value
  let flood-prob random-normal 0.26 0.22
  
  ; Select the closest prob (could also average the depths values instead if preferred)
  let dif-vals map [ i -> abs ( i - flood-prob ) ] probabilities
  let dif-index position ( min dif-vals ) dif-vals
  let closest-depth item dif-index depths
  
  print word "flood-prob: " flood-prob
  print word "closest prob: " item dif-index probabilities
  
  report closest-depth
end
```

Note that I've moved the definition of probabilities / depths to the setup so that it's only being called on setup, rather than within the reporter.